# I can't seem to understand Mongoose's "findOne"

Tags: javascript, mongodb, model-view-controller, mean

Ok, So I have this function to get a blog Post with an id from a mongodb db.

```
 exports.blogPostFirst = function(req, res, next) {

     BlogPost.findOne({    
         _id: '1'
     }, function(err, e) {
         if (err) {
             return next(err);
         } else {
             req.content = e;
             next();
         }
     });

     res.render('blogPage', {
         title: req.content.title,
         content: req.content.html_content
     })
 };
```

Now for, some reason, the `_id : '1'` part does not work, the _id field is a String.

When I instead give the _id parameter a value in the from of an element form a route eg I have in my routes 'route::param'

and I give the function above a 4th argument 'id' and pass it as a the "param" parameter it works just fine, however I'm at a loss for how I can manually set the "_id" field.

The `BlogPost` objects is as follows:

```
var BlogPost = require('mongoose').model('Post');
```

the mongoose schema is:

```
Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var PostSchema = new Schema({
    title: String,
    html_content: String,
    _id: String,
});

mongoose.model('Post', PostSchema);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so, after thinking about it clearly for a fraction of second I saw my problem.
When I write:

```
BlogPost.findOne({    
     _id: '1'
 }, function(err, e) {
     if (err) {
         return next(err);
     } else {
         req.content = e;
         next();
     }
 });
```

I set the .content parameter of the request o be equal to "e" (the result of my `findOne` query), however after the `findOne` function is "finished" req.content doesn't keep it value, `req.content`, rather, exists only within the environment of that function, so I ought to call the function like this:

```
exports.blogPostFirst = function(req, res, next) {

     BlogPost.findOne({    
         _id: '1'
     }, function(err, e) {
         if (err) {
             return next(err);
         } else {
             req.content = e;
             next();
              res.render('blogPage', {
         title: req.content.title,
         content: req.content.html_content
     })
         }
     }); 
 };
```

What baffles me is why this has worked at all when I have used it with parameters passed from the URL... or maybe I have found the fix but my reasoning for the fix is bad. Anyway, I have my answer, but I can't delete this, so I shall just leave it here